# ("node_modules/next/types/index")' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to setup a custom server using next.js as detailed in the [nextjs documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next), but this time, I'm using typescript. I keep getting `("node_modules/next/types/index")' has no compatible call signatures`. It seems I'm not importing nextjs the right way. What am I missing?

```
import "isomorphic-fetch";
import next from "next"; // I also tried import * as next from "next

const dev = (process as any).env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });  // Typescript is complaining on this line.
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT: I'm using the latest version v8.1.1-canary.55 nextjs**

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a [known issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7529). Downgrading `next^8.1.0` fixed the issue.